# Multiple Query Insert and Return

Tags: insert, bulk-insert, set-returning-functions

I have the following code which creates a Mapbox Vector Tile(MVT). At the moment it creates, stores and returns to the user. I would like however to create multiple in one query however i'm getting stuck on the insert and return parts. Here's what I have so far

```
WITH mvtgeom AS 
(
SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 5, 0 -5, 0 0))'),
ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096, 4096)),
4096, 0, false)
)

INSERT INTO tile( mvt)
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom)
FROM   mvtgeom
RETURNING *;
```

I would like to do this many times in one execution however simitlar to below:

```
WITH 
mvtgeom AS
(
SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 5, 0 -5, 0 0))'),
ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096, 4096)),
4096, 0, false)
),

mvtgeom1 AS
(
SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 5, 0 -5, 0 0))'),
ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096, 4096)),
4096, 0, false)
),

INSERT INTO tile(mvt) 
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom)
FROM   mvtgeom

INSERT INTO tile(mvt) 
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom1)
FROM   mvtgeom1

RETURNING *;
```

The with part works fine but later on insert it fails. I feel like i'm missing something fundamental with the insert statement and then the return.

Comment: What database system and version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps instead of 2 separate insert statements, you can combine them with an UNION? Like

```
INSERT INTO tile(mvt) 
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom)
FROM   mvtgeom
UNION ALL
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom1)
FROM   mvtgeom1

RETURNING *;
```

Comment: Excellent, worked perfectly